# CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Visual Studio 11 Win64"

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2012

I get with CMake 2.8.9 the following error:

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Visual Studio 11 Win64". CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set. You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:H:/ogredeps/CMakeFiles/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:H:/ogredeps/CMakeFiles/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I am using Visual C++ 2012 Express on Windows 7 64.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are facing this bug: http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=13348

You might have a luck with [CMake 2.8.10-RC1](http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.10-rc1-win32-x86.exe)